# Display the result of an FQL query within an application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Really new to Facebook Development. So I am running this query"

SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()

and the response i get from Graph API explorer is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "friend_count": 175
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want this result to show up in the app that I am developing, I run the following code

```
 $fc = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()'
  ));
```

Now I cant figure out how to display the number...

Also if this helps print_r($fc) give the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [friend_count] => 175
        )

)
```

Thanks for your help, and do excuse me if I havent posted the question properly, still figuring out how to use this awesome website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an array with only one element at index 0. This element is an array as well, which contains a value with the `friend_count` key.

```
echo $fc[0]["friend_count"];
```